# Any good C# library for signal processing?

Tags: discrete-signals, filter-design

Does anyone can link me to a good C# DSP library? I saw some good C++ libraries but I don't have much with C++. Is there any way to wrap them ?

My main porpuse is to apply some filters(Lowpass, Highpass,Notch....) on a a buffer. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can recommend these libraries:

[**BASS**](http://www.un4seen.com/) - also has lot's of functions. Although it is not written for C#, they provide you with a wrapper (Bass.Net). Keep in mind that if you want to use this library in commercial project then you have to pay for the license.

[**NAudio**](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) - is a mature project with lots of functions and support for variety of codecs.

[**cscore**](https://github.com/filoe/cscore) - rather new project with some nice capabilities, especially for visualizations, and some codecs that NAudio is missing. You might want to give it a try at some point, or even contribute to it.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommendate the lib [NWaves](https://github.com/ar1st0crat/NWaves), not so mature, but enough for most of cases in life.

Comment: This is definitely the lib to go, nowadays.